# Flood fill algorithm uncovers all area (Minesweeper)

Tags: c++, algorithm, flood-fill, minesweeper

I'm implementing flood fill algorithm for minesweeper game on C++ and all is fine, but I'am not enjoyed the result of it's work. It's uncovers all area except bombs when in right version it needs to uncover some area with numbers, that represents amount of bombs nearby.

```
void floodfill(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= cellsX || y >= cellsY) // Check game field borders
        return;
    if (closedMap[x][y] == EMPTY && !visited[x][y]) // If this cell is empty and not visited...
    {
        openedMap[x][y] = closedMap[x][y];
        visited[x][y] = true;
        floodfill(x + 1, y);
        floodfill(x, y + 1);
        floodfill(x - 1, y);
        floodfill(x, y - 1);
    }
    else if (closedMap[x][y] > EMPTY && closedMap[x][y] < CLOSED && !visited[x][y]) // If this cell is contains number and not visited...
    {
        openedMap[x][y] = closedMap[x][y];
        visited[x][y] = true;
        floodfill(x + 1, y);
        floodfill(x, y + 1);
        floodfill(x - 1, y);
        floodfill(x, y - 1);
    }
    return;
}
```

Some matrixes for simple understanding:

```
How it is (* means covered): 
   [1][2][3][4][5]
[1]    1  *  2  *
[2]    1  2  4  2
[3]    2  *  3  *
[4]    2  *  4  2
[5]    1  1  2  *
How it must be:
   [1][2][3][4][5]
[1]    1  *  *  *
[2]    1  *  *  *
[3]    2  *  *  *
[4]    2  *  *  *
[5]    1  *  *  *
```

Comment: Hard to be sure but I expect `if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x > cellsX || y > cellsY)` really should be     `if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= cellsX || y >= cellsY)`

Comment: Oh yes, it should be like that. Just edited.

Comment: *"all is fine"* -- if this was true, you wouldn't have a question for us.

Comment: Problem is still unsolved, just with this correction algorithm will work better (in my version x or y can be bigger than it should), but the main problem this correction doesn't decide. (sorry for answering too late).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like you are treating a spaced filled with a number the same as a blank space. If you assign a number to a tile you wouldn't need to `floodfill()` past it.

Comment: I'm used floodfill() for filling closed cells as empty one and in this case numbers can't be shown (if i understand you correctly).

Comment: Hmm seems like it's work now. I'm post here a altered version of algorithm, btw thank you for your hint.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in that that I'm just flood filled number tiles as a spaced tiles and this just uncovered all area except mines instead of just some area. Now if function found a number it's stops and draws number.

```
    else if (closedMap[x][y] > EMPTY && closedMap[x][y] < CLOSED) // If this cell is contains number...
    {
        openedMap[x][y] = closedMap[x][y];
        return;
    }
```